# Parsing array inside object with unknown key and unknown values

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON (snippet):

```
"1": {
  "Name": [
    "Person1",
    "Person2",
    "Person3",
    "Person4",
    "Person5"
  ]
}
"4"{
  "Name": [
    "AnotherPerson1",
    "AnotherPerson2",
    "AnotherPerson3",
    "AnotherPerson4",
    "AnotherPerson5"
  ]
}
...
```

I don't know the key value (it doesn't increase linearly) and I don't know the different values inside "Name" (only that they are inside "Name", are strings, and total 5).

I want to return all first strings under "Name" and their respective root(?) key. So "Person1" & "1"; "AnotherPerson1" & "4", etc.

I've only managed to make it work when I know the key value but it's too long to write.

```
console.log(data[1]["Name"][1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);

keys.forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(data[key].Name[0], 'on root key', key);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) array to map the data to a more useful structure.

I'm not 100% clear what the structure you are looking for is but I think what you want is something like:

```js
const data={1:{Name:["Person1","Person2","Person3","Person4","Person5"]},4:{Name:["AnotherPerson1","AnotherPerson2","AnotherPerson3","AnotherPerson4","AnotherPerson5"]}};

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((a,[key,{Name}])=> {
   Name.forEach(name => a.push({name, key}));
   return a;
},[]);

console.log(res)
```